# You can use a local server together with browser sync (gulp)

Tags: php, gulp, browser-sync

I have time using gulp, but I would like to know if using a local PHP server I can update the page immediately, or in its absence any other tool that allows me to update every change to PHP files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a php task to your gulpfile.

```
var src = {
   php:'./public_html/**/*.php',
};


gulp.task('php', function(){
    gulp.src(src.php)
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});


gulp.task ('watch', function(){
// other watch tasks    
  gulp.watch(src.php, ['php']);

});
```